# LMAX Disruptor version 3.x sample codes

Tags: java, disruptor-pattern

Has anybody written a complete (not snippets) basic example on how to use version 3.x of the LMAX Disruptor? I've seen code samples on version 2.x in the official wiki and other places but haven't found any basic examples for version 3.x. There's one using [Scala](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lmax-disruptor/RHjGcX6P6MY) and a Java [alternative](http://bad-concurrency.blogspot.com/2013/12/an-alternative-multi-producer-approach.html) multiproducer implementation. I was surprised that I can find an alternative example and can't find a basic one. As of now, I'm using the test cases to see how the individual components work. Would be great if there's an example you could refer to so you can see how all the new components work together. Thanks in advance to those who would reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Disruptor [wiki](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/wiki/) at github has an up to date [getting started](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/wiki/Getting-Started) page which does put together a working example.

The Disruptor API should hopefully be self explanatory. Do you have a more specific question about the API or its usage?

Comment: Thanks Sam! This is exactly what I was looking for! Yay! :)